# Can JLabel replace Jpanel as container?

Tags: java

Usually i will use Jpanel as container, what if i use jlabel to replace jpanel.

what is jpanel advantage over jlabel for background layout purposes? 
i have not start using jlabel as container yet..i am now consulting SO before i do the next step.

as you can see below i am using jlabel as container not jpanel. i chose jlabel instead because i can set icon on jlabel and i think it easieer to maintain than jpanel

[image]

Comment: I believe that the answer is yes, but understand that JLabels are not opaque default, and use a null layout by default, but like a JPanel, can be given any layout.

Comment: yes, i think i can agree with that.

Comment: Check out [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for more ideas and suggestions on this topic. If you decide to use the label then you also want to consider using the [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrow from  Hovercraft Full Of Eels comment,

Jlabel can be used as container but it has no other layout except absolute/null layout by default. Overall it can be applied. only Jlabel  was by default not opaque.